# Call python script from command line, which exists in another directory

Tags: python, bash, shell

My project structure:

```
/Users/user1/home/bashScrpts/shellScript.sh 
/Users/user1/home/pyScrpts/pyScrpt.py
```

From the shell script I want to call a function of pyScrpt.py

Content of 
pyScrpt.py

```
def test():
return sys.argv[1]
```

shellScript.sh

```
    DATA="testXX"
    cmd="import sys;sys.path.insert(0, '/Users/user1/home/pyScrpts/pyScrpt');import pyScrpt; print pyScrpt.test()"
    xy=$(python -c  \'${cmd}\' "${DATA}")
    echo $xy
```

Error I am getting:

```
  File "<string>", line 1
   'import
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

I don't see whats going wrong here.

Can anyone help me on this??

Comment: thanks for the reply but if want to run python script inline from bash I need single quotes. I tried double quotes also but facing same issue.

Comment: then this [faq?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ#BashFAQ.2F050.I.27m_trying_to_put_a_command_in_a_variable.2C_but_the_complex_cases_always_fail.21)

Comment: One more problem: Since you import `pyScrpt`, `sys.argv[1]` will generate an `IndexError`

Comment: I guess it wont complain @Hai because I am passing the arg to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to replace `\'` in  `\'${cmd}\'` with double quotes `"${cmd}"`.

Also you should add `import sys` to your `pyScrpt.py`.

Comment: thanks!!!! that solved the error but getting the following error now:
    ImportError: No module named pyScrpt

Comment: You have to change the path for python script; sys.path.insert(0, '/Users/user1/home/pyScrpts/pyScrpt')  to sys.path.insert(0, '/Users/user1/home/pyScrpts')

Comment: why is that? what should give as a path then?

Answer (score 0):

I have never done this before, but i would hazard a guess that it may be due to the wrong function structure, it should read:

`def test()
     return sys.argv[1]`